# Proof that holomorphic function $f$ is injective.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Given the holomorphic function $f$ on the unit disc ($\mathbb{D}$) and the derivative holds the following inequality for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$ such that $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$:
$$ |f'(z)-ze^z|<\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{Re(z)}$$

I am supposed to prove that $f$ cannot be injective. I am completely clueless how to work on this. In now that geometrically this is a bout the circle with radius 0.5. By Schwarz‘s Lemma this has to be mapped onto a smaller circle under a holomorphic function. But other than that I am blank. Does anyone have any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $|ze^{z}|=\frac 1 2 e^{Re \, z}$ when $|z|=\frac 1  2$.

Use Rouche's Theorem  to  concldue that $f'(z)$ and $ze^{z}$ have the same number of zeros inside the circle. This implies that $f'(z)$ has a zero inside $|z|=\frac 1  2$. But the derivative of an injective holomorohic map never vanishes.

Answer (score 1):

By Rouché's theorem one has that $f'(x)$ has a zero in $|z|<1/2$ and it is known that the derivative of holomorphic injective functions never vanishes (you probably saw this already, it's another application of Rouché's theorem).